# MYSQL Workbench keeps importing illegal characters for the 'id' column

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, mysql-workbench

I keep on trying to import a CSV file, about 4000 chars long, into my MYSQL DB, via WorkBench...

Every time the ID column has an illegal character in it.

Why would MYSQL Workbench do this?

Right now it says \ufeffid ... so there is some character \ufeff before 'id'.

I exported my XLSX file as a CSV. It shouldnt have these characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the [Unicode BOM](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark) character (code point/glyph), a zero-width space used to mark Unicode files as first character in the file. It is redundant (bad practice as we see), but so Windows Notepad discovers UTF-8 instead of the local charset.

With manual copying the first line, this BOM character may be copied to several lines in a file.

Somehow, somewhere, you need to get rid of them.

---

*About the BOM, Byte-Order-Mark:*

Unicode numbers all possible glyphs, code points, chars.
The conversion to binary data is in the form of UTF-8 (multi-byte), UTF-16LE (little endian), UTF-16BE (big endian), and UTF-32 LE/BE.
By a BOM character the encoding can be detected. For that it is U+FEFF, two different byte values.

Comment: I exported the file into TXT tab delimited, then I saved that file as CSV. Seemst o have worked. THanks for this info.